# How to configure Blazor client to perform authentication using external IdentityServer4 server

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-client-side

We are developing a new product consisting of a Blazor server (targeting .NET Core 3 and using ElectronNET.API 5.22.14) and Blazor client (targeting .NET Standard 2.1).

We don't want to host an identity server in the Blazor server, because we have an existing IdentityServer4 server.

Is it possible to display a login page with Login/Register options in the Blazor client that authenticates via the IdentityServer4 server (e.g. local DB login in identity server)?  - All the examples I have found online hosts the identity server in the Blazor server.

Is there an example or section in documentation online that outlines the correct setup of the Blazor client? E.g. how to configure the `Startup.cs`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.  I'm creating a simple token passing schema without any external plugins.  I'm sure there is some way it won't be as good but it gets the job done without external dependencies.  Still, this approach looks solid.

https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-authentication-with-clientside-blazor-using-webapi-aspnet-core-identity/

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly possible.
For Blazor Web assembly (front-end hosting mode) we can do the following.

Let's assume we have an IdentityServer 4 running on `https://localhost:5001` and a Client SPA application with Blazor Web Assembly running on `https://localhost:5003`

For Identity Server let's configure a new client.

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "spa",
    ClientUri = "https://localhost:5003",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

    RequireClientSecret = false, // for auth code flow there is no secret required as it couldn't be securely stored in the front-end anyway

    // where to redirect to after login
    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/authentication/login-callback" },
    
    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5003/signout-callback-oidc" },

    // CORS
    AllowedCorsOrigins =     { "https://localhost:5003" },

    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1"
    }
}
```

For Blazor app, let's assume we have created a default one and selected authentication `Store user accounts in-app` so that it creates the boilerplate for login functionality and it adds the package

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="3.2.1" />
```

Now we have to configure the Blazor client app's OpenId Connect settings at Program.cs.

Note that there is an appsettings.json that could be read with `builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);` by default, for for simplicity's sake we can manually hardcode settings.

```
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(
    options =>
    {
        //let's hardcode the values for now. We can enable reading from settings later.
        //builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);

        options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "spa";
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("openid");
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("profile");
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultScopes.Add("api1");
        options.ProviderOptions.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:5003/counter";
        options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:5003/authentication/login-callback";
        options.ProviderOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    });
```

That configuration should be enough for the blazor app to redirect to Identity Server to ask credentials and to store the token once a user has been authenticated.